# preg_match PHP phone numbers

Tags: php, preg-match

Need to find a preg_match pattern for the phone numbers below (a mixture of more than one, have kept all in one var), am getting the one preceded with 'Tel,Toll Free' but not the one on new line..looking for some help..or sugestion

```
preg_match_all('/((.*)|\s)?\s*?\:\s*?([0-9 A-Z a-z \-\+\.\,\/\(\)(Ext))]*)/i

$phAr="Tel: 813-227-4500(+787 45 55 56)
 Tel : 002-6598-6554 (+98-214-214)

(509) 878 9856 658

Tel: 888 (408) 546-777 Ext 1122 or 1133

Tel: 888 (408) 546-000 (TollFree)

 Toll Free: 1-125-PYS-PYS(145-547-554-45)

Tel: +88 555-988 (408)/(999)

Toll: 1-125-PYS-4YOU (Mr. Toran)
Toll Free: 1-125-PYS-PYS

+9999-888-66655 (258)

Tel: 813-227-4500 Ext 1254 / 8525

Phone : (855) 834-7487 

+1-9999-888-66655-PYS-PYS

(+98-987-658498)

99-408-546-099 (Mr. Reigh O)
Address1 Part1
8760 North Address2.
Address2 00
9999
";
```

Comment: @john, am not able to find the comprehensive solution for the pattern as it exist in my query. Also, i did mention the partial success with the pattern provided. Any help again will be appreciated!

Comment: On, breaking down the string above...the address provided gets affected, and there's no pattern for the address, numbers, CAPS letter in address are also matched by preg_match.